# Returning Row Index from JavaScript function ,returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, return-value

```
    function getRowIndex() {
    var tble = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < tble.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tble.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            tble.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {

                return this.parentElement.rowIndex;
            }
        }
    }
}
var rIndex = getRowIndex();
console.log(rIndex);
```

This function `getRowIndex()` is returning undefined when I try to print index. I want to extract the row index value in value when clicked, using `javaScript`.

Comment: there is no return value for the `getRowIndex` you have created an anonynous callback function with a return statatement for onclick property of cells, but nothing that would return stuff from getRowIndex

Comment: When I do console.log() instead of return it prints the rowIndex so how can I return the same value ?

Comment: `getRowIndex` seems to be a function that assigns click event handlers to the cells of your table, so its name is misleading. Please explain what you are trying to do exactly, because that function does not seem like it should be returning any index.

Comment: I am creating the table using HTML DOM.If you want , you can check complete code here:-  https://jsfiddle.net/devansh8373/5Lbrgf0k/1/#

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using HTML `table` element. You can find row index like this:

```js
document.getElementById('myTable').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'TD') {
    alert(e.target.parentNode.rowIndex);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using `event delegation` here. Instead of iterating over each child element and then bind the event. I am binding the event to parent node itself and then find the click target using `event.target`. This has great performance benefits as you can already see.

Comment: I am creating the table using HTML DOM and this isn't working

Comment: Do you mean: you are using JavaScript to create the table? The code you have shared has an event handler ``onclick``. Your return statement is inside event handler function and not the parent function. So obviously you won't get ``rowIndex`` this way. You might have to change the solution. You can share a jsfiddle with me so that I know what exactly you want to achieve. May be I can help you out there.

Comment: Sure, here is the link - https://jsfiddle.net/devansh8373/5Lbrgf0k/1/#&togetherjs=gS8hLlf47i

Comment: Hi @DevanshPandey, Looking at your code, I have created a fiddle implements the functionality that you want to implement. Here's the link to it: https://jsfiddle.net/y5jx379b/

Comment: Please note that you don't need row and column indexes to implement it.